# Misunderstanding the additive rule in probability?

Tags: probability

I play a game called genshin impact but to simplify the problem I have, let's say we are rolling for a prize. On the first roll, there is a probability of $0.006$ of getting it. Second, $0.066$, third $0.126$, $0.186$, adding $6$% every time. If I use the multiplicative rule, the probability of not getting it on the first roll is $0.994$, second is $0.934$, and getting it on neither first nor second is $0.994 \cdot 0.934$. If we keep repeating this over the chance that by the $10$th roll we haven't gotten the price a single time is $3$%, and it gradually diminishes.

However, here's the problem:
If I use the additive rule, the first roll has a $0.006$ probability, the second a $0.066$, so the chance that i got it on one of the two rolls is $0.006+0.066= 0.072$. In other words, a $7$% chance i got it on either the first or the second. If I let this keep going, by the $7$th roll I'm already guaranteed to have gotten the prize on one of the rolls, could be any of them.

Isn't there a contradiction here? With the additive rule I have it by the $7$th roll, but with multiplicative, I might never get it? It's only getting closer and closer to $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additive rule works only when the possibilities are mutually exclusive, which isn't the case here.

In other words, the additive rule would be appropriate if winning the prize on round $x$ made it impossible to win the prize on any other round.  But because it's possible to win the prize both on round $1$ and round $2$, you have to subtract from the sum the probability that you in fact win the prize on both rounds.